# Foursquare user check in V2

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, signature, foursquare

I am using Foursquare's v2 to allow a user to sign in to a given venue. I am trying to sign the request, but so far I am getting the following

```
u'meta': {
  u'errorType': u'param_error',
  u'code': 400,
  u'errorDetail': u'Invalid checkin id'
},
u'response': {

}
}
```

The way I am doing it is as follows, the mobile user sends a request to my webpage with the venue ID and their user id and the web handler does the following

```
        venueID = self.request.get("venue")
        user = self.request.get("user")
        params = {    
                  'oauth_token': user
        }
        consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key=keys.CLIENT_ID,secret=keys.CLIENT_SECRET)
        params.update({'signature': hunchMethods.sign_request(params, keys.CLIENT_SECRET)})
        check_in_req = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/" + venueID + "?" + urllib.urlencode(params)
        print check_in_req

        url1 = fetch(check_in_req)
        json_response = simplejson.loads(url1.content.encode('utf-8')) 
        print json_response
```

My sign request method is as follows:

```
def sign_request(query_dict, data):
    queries = sorted( (unicode(k).encode('utf-8'), unicode(v).encode('utf-8'))
                      for k,v in query_dict.iteritems() )
    data = urllib.urlencode(queries) + data
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Drew I realised that I was trying to implement the wrong method, I have since my updated my code to be

```
def post(self, info):
        venueID = self.request.get("venue")
        user = self.request.get("user")
        venue = venue_id_change.retrieveNewID(venueID, user)
        url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add?venueId=" +venue+ "&oauth_token=" + user + "&broadcast=private"
        logging.info(url)
        url1 = fetch(url)
        json_response = simplejson.loads(url1.content.encode('utf-8'))
```

Although this does not seem to do anything :-( Am I missing something?

Comment: You're not actually signing the request in the `sign_request` method - you're just appending the secret key to the query string. Shouldn't you be using an HMAC there? Or better, using an existing oauth library to make the requests so you don't have to compute the signature yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the wrong API method.

[The method you're using](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/checkins.html) takes a checkin ID and returns details of the existing checkin.

[This one](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add.html) takes a venue ID and creates a new checkin.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that was the one I was trying to use, for example when I request https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/y?oauth_token=x I get an `Invalid checkin id`. What would the correct request layout be? :-)

Comment: POST to https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add and include the venue or venueId as a parameter inside the request body.

Comment: Should this return response, apologies if this is an obvious question but I have little experience with POST request and this does not return anything :-(

Comment: Yes, it should return a response with a checkin object. This is all in the API documentation on the 2nd link.